# Handle wrong password event on fb integration using FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

Hello i have used below code for integrating fb in my ios application and it is working successfully. But here one strange thing is happens when i try wrong id/password and then after i enters the correct id and password it redirects me to the facebook webview and my profile open strange one. It should redirect to my app. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login Error : %@", error.description);
    }
    else if(result.isCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login Cancel By User");
    }
    else
    {
        [self fetchUserDataForFacebookLogin];
        //[login logOut];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Getting same issue. If user enters wrong password first time and giving correct password next time then this issue will occurs. Hope you will get answer.

Comment: No i haven't get the answer yet if anything that help please let me know

Comment: Wait for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a facebook SDK bug check [here is the submitted bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1684079998480422/) And as par facebook developer team that will be fix in next update:

[image]

Comment: Actually i was submit the bug yesterday https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/997425360302820 but already this bug submit so my bug murge with older